# Multiple outputformats in single map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, parquet

I have a mapreduce job which reads text file and creates parquet file from it and at the same time writes to simple text file as output. I have used multiple output format for that. But multiple output format object can be initialize for either writing parquet file or text file at a time. I need to accommodate both in single mapper. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way, but you can just initialize a StringBuilder in our mapper's `setup()` method, append all text values to it during the `map()` method and then write it to disk in the `cleanup` method. Depends on the size of your text output and if you have enough memory or not. That way the text file doesn't need to be a mapper output at all, and your mapper output can be the Parquet data only.

You could use `context.getInputSplit()` or something similar as the text output file names so that each mapper outputs a unique file name and you know which output correponds to which input.